# Delete items using Apple's new api NSFileProviderReplicatedExtension

Tags: xcode, macos, fileprovider

We are using Apple's new api NSFileProviderReplicatedExtension to implement a file provider extension.
We can use this extension to synchronize files from a remote file server.When there are changes on the server，we can signal `workingset` to update the local copy.
But when a directory with many files is deleted on the server, we can't delete this directory by calling `observer.didDeleteItems`.Can someone give me some advice?
The Apple's documents is here:[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/replicated_file_provider_extension/synchronizing_the_file_provider_extension)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit the question.

Comment: Can you be more precise @feiniks ? The information is too vague. We roughly do the same and it works.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, after we delete the item corresponding to the directory from the workingset, it works fine now too.